# TypeScript: Providing generic type, array vs tuple, for database data

Tags: typescript, types

I'm using the [mssql](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#readme) library which has this `interface`:

```
export interface IRecordSet<T> extends Array<T> {
    columns: IColumnMetadata;
    toTable(name?: string): Table;
}
```

I have a function that gets data from a database and returns an array of `IRecordSet<T>`, so that's an array of arrays which contain the generic type `<T>`. This looks like:

`[[{}, {}, ...], [{}, {}, ...], ...]`

```
import { IRecordSet } from 'mssql'

type Data<T> = Array<IRecordSet<T>>

async function getData (sql: string): Promise<Data<any>> {
  // connect to db, run sql
  return []
}
```

Now I need a function that calls `getData()`, and I'd like to type the actual returned data by providing the generic type in `IRecordSet<T>`.

I know this doesn't work, but this is what I have right now:

```
interface BookData {
  name: string
  author: string
}
interface CarData {
  make: string
  model: string
}

type BooksAndCars = Data<[BookData, CarData]>

async function getBooksAndCars (): Promise<void> {
  const myData: BooksAndCars = await getData(`
    SELECT name, author FROM Books;
    SELECT make, model FROM Cars;
  `)

  const firstBook: BookData = myData[0][0]
  const cars: CarData[] = myData[1]

  // ...
}
```

TypeScript is saying:

- `Type '[BookData, CarData]' is not assignable to type 'BookData'.`
- `Type 'IRecordSet<[BookData, CarData]>' is not assignable to type 'CarData[]'.`

I understand these errors, but I don't know how to type the `myData`, `firstBook` & `cars` variables using the interfaces defined (`BookData` & `CarData`).

What should `type BooksAndCars = Data<[BookData, CarData]>` be..?

Comment: It should be: `type BooksAndCars = Data<[Array<BookData>,Array< CarData>]>` ?

Comment: Presumably it should be like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wenBBN) but your `Data` type is not quite compatible with it, since you are claiming to know that the resulting array will have exactly two elements and `Data` is an arbitrary array of unknown length... so you'll need a type assertion like `await getData(...) as BooksAndCars`.  If that works for you I can write up an answer; if not, please elaborate on unsatisfied use cases, preferably with a version of `getData()` that returns actual sample data.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you, the type assertion seems work. It is indeed the case that `getData()` needs to return any length array (as it's based on the sql passed in), and that at the point we call `getData()` we then know the length of the array as that's where the sql is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want `BooksAndCars` to be a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of exactly two elements of different types:

```
type BooksAndCars = [IRecordSet<BookData>, IRecordSet<CarData>];
```

But the `getData()` function returns a `Promise<Data<any>>`, or equivalently a `Promise<Array<IRecordSet<any>>>`.  And unfortunately for your use case, that means `myData` will be of type `Array<IRecordSet<any>>`, an array of unknown length where the first and second elements are of indistinguishable types.  It is considered a type error in TypeScript for you to assign such an unknown-length homogeneous array to a two-element heterogeneous tuple, since the compiler cannot guarantee that the returned array has exactly two elements of the right type in the right order.

If *you* are sure that what you're doing is safe, and want to forgo type checking by the compiler, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler not to worry about it:

```
async function getBooksAndCars(): Promise<void> {
  const myData = await getData(`
    SELECT name, author FROM Books;
    SELECT make, model FROM Cars;
  `) as BooksAndCars

  const firstBook = myData[0][0];
  const cars: CarData[] = myData[1]

  // ...
}
```

I think a type assertion is probably the way to go here because `getData()`'s return type involves [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) so you already gave up on type safety guarantees.  It isn't much worse to assume that you're getting back a tuple than it is to assume you're getting back an array of `BookData | CarData`.  You have to be careful either way that your sql query really will return data of the length and types you expect.

If you did really care about type safety, you'd write runtime code to check the length and types, and then we could talk about how to make the compiler recognize that your checks should [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) from `Promise<Data<object>>` (or something) to `BooksAndCars`.  But I won't go down that route here, since it's out of scope for the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUIIPZQCYDKEYAPACoB8yEAHpCHgM7ICCUUcAnuVQN4CwAKGTIcAGwCuAWxCMAXMjghOAbiEiw2MnABGYiAAoQcKRAD8CxmCigA5gEoFS1UIC+QsJwAOKACJwwOB5kAF5Wdi4SDCxcQmIeCiEhOEZOEARkGAl0sGBsEGRbYn9Ag0YARzFLaztHZAAFKGwpYEYIEhKg5wo+dWQAen7RfJAsMGRNZDwdABpkKGzkCrE+qGIJKAKAbQBdNyFQSFhEFAAhbGwAa07kAWFkY1NqmxBbPrgJMAALXGe7fcEh2g8CQyAAwnAoDc7iIpHBLhA-q8+lJsHgIFUljVkYJ3IIPN4zhdLowWAwIVBmGEttEcPgiKRzldOhQ5rTYgySBSWTs1PjBCk0hksjk8gUimAmSSyXgKYwDHVGs1Wu0AG7YYB4Xr3HCycZSTg3MJwADucGA4wlnQMAAM+iICABRAAyjrBZAeJggcw+31wyAAYugAPIAWWQUsYfJEDpdbo9cIRc1R6LEgZD4bl0eQNvsimYkZlcqSOvyVkywEpkuJoWQBs6WwADDsm7y+rrywhIfJwZCGzta-WAnAtgBGPb8kSDZAAOjnbiAA)